# How to get the size of a number in .net?

Tags: c#, mathematical-expressions

I want with a given double number to return its "size" (known as |number|, or number of digit without the numbers after the dot), for example:

```
12.324654 -> 2
12 -> 2
0.99 -> 0
1.01 -> 1
901 -> 3
-0.99 -> 0
-9.999 -> 1
```

There must be a function is .net that I dont familiar with that does it..

Thanks.

Comment: Typically, |number| denotes the absolute value - which is not what you are after, obviously.

Comment: The *integral* part of the number is to the left of the decimal point.  The *fractional* part is to the right.  So you are seeking a way to measure the number of decimal places used by the integral part.

Comment: |number| also known as a size of a group/number. It connect to what you are walking about..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
((int)Math.Abs(12.324654)).ToString().Length
```

`Math.Abs` will convert to positive number (don't want to count the negative sign)
`(int)` will drop the digits following the decimal point
`ToString()` converts to a string ===> "12"
`Length` tells you how many characters there are
there is an edge case where `(int)( some number ) == 0`, where the length is going to give you 1-- you may not want this, so be aware of the possibility

now, what you COULD do is make this an extention method....

```
public static class Utils
{
   public static int Size(this double n)
   {
     int i = (int)Math.Abs(n);
     if ( i == 0 ) return 0;
     return  i.ToString().Length;
   }
}

12.324654.Size() == 2;
```

Comment: Pretty straight forward :) +1 I like the simplicity.

Comment: Doesn't account for negative numbers.  You'd need the absolute value, otherwise the requirement in the original question (-9.999 -> 1) wouldn't work.  Maybe ((int)(Math.Abs(12.324654)).ToString().Length; ? Otherwise, I like the simplicity of this approach.

Comment: :)  Now it's been updated, I'll delete my answer. :)  I think it needs to account for the possibility of the result being 0 though, since the OP wanted 0 to return a zero length...

Comment: 0.99 -> 0 will also return 1, isn't it?

Comment: @hungryMind, "(int)(someDouble)" will drop the part after the decimal point, so (int)0.99 == 1 (because of the 0) --- changed the code to fix this

Comment: Thats what I am saying, 0.99 expects 0 as result, but ur formula will return 1. This one will work ok, ((int)Math.Abs(yourNumber *10)).ToString().Length - 1

Comment: @hungryMind, you are right. I added comments about the edge case. thanks!

Comment: @muad what about my solution? isn't it straight forwrd

Answer (score 13):

Try log<sub>10</sub>(max(abs(*number*), 0.5)) + 1 rounded down.

Or, in actual C# syntax:

```
(int)(Math.Log10(Math.Max(Math.Abs(number), 0.5)) + 1)
```

---

**OK, how does that work?**

At first of all, *p* = log<sub>10</sub>(*x*) is the base-10 [logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) of *x*; that is to say, the value such that 10 raised to the *p*-th power (or 1 followed by *p* zeros) equals *x*.  The logarithm essentially measures the length of the number, except that it's a smooth function of *x*:

[image: Graph of the base-10 logarithm of x]

(Note that, in languages that don't provide a base-10 logarithm function, we can always calculate it as log<sub>10</sub>(*x*) = log(*x*) / log(10), where log() is the logarithm function in any base.)

For example, we have

> log<sub>10</sub>(1) = 0.0 
>   log<sub>10</sub>(10) = 1.0 
>   log<sub>10</sub>(100) = 2.0 
>   log<sub>10</sub>(1000) = 3.0

but also e.g.:

> log<sub>10</sub>(5) = 0.69897 
>   log<sub>10</sub>(50) = 1.69897 
>   log<sub>10</sub>(500) = 2.69897 
>   log<sub>10</sub>(5000) = 3.69897

In general, *n* ≤ log<sub>10</sub>(*x*) < *n*+1 whenever 10<sup>*n*</sup> ≤ *x* < 10<sup>*n*+1</sup>.

Looking at the values above, it should be easy enough to see that, to get the number of base-10 digits in a whole number, we should round its base-10 logarithm down to the nearest whole number and add 1 (because we want the length of 10 to be 2, not 1).

However, there are a few more edge cases to consider:

First, the original questioner wanted the length of −*x* to equal the length of *x*.  The logarithm is only defined for positive numbers, so we replace *x* by its absolute value to make it always positive.

Second, the original questioner also wanted the length of numbers between 0 and 1 to be zero.  The logarithm, however, can take arbitrarily large negative values:

> log<sub>10</sub>(0.1) = −1.0 
>   log<sub>10</sub>(0.01) = −2.0 
>   log<sub>10</sub>(0.001) = −3.0 
>   log<sub>10</sub>(0.0001) = −4.0

and indeed, log<sub>10</sub>(0) = −∞. To satisfy this requirement, we simply make sure that the number whose length we calculate can never go below 0.5 by using the maximum of it and 0.5 as the input to log<sub>10</sub>().  (We could use any number between 0.1 and 1 as the cutoff, but 0.5 happens to be a nice round binary fraction.)

Also, we have to make sure to add +1 to the logarithm *before* rounding it, so that the number that we round is always non-negative.  That's because `(int)` in C# actually rounds negative numbers *up* towards zero.  For example, since log<sup>10</sup>(0.5) ≈ −0.3, the expression `(int)Math.Log10(0.5) + 1` (rounding before addition) would evaluate to 0+1 = 1  rather than the expected 0.

Comment: How can you log a negative number?

Comment: @Daok: You can't, sorry.  Corrected.

Comment: Can you explain it to me. I do not understand the logic behind but found it very wise + 1

Comment: @Ilmari: How about input 0? And I don't know C#, but will the min() function force it to return 0?

Comment: OK, I added an explanation, and also corrected the min() to max().  (Thanks, @Ziyao Wei!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation!!
I'll not use this because I know that in time, when I'll need to maintenance the code - this line wont make any sense to me.. Also my numbers arent that big, so currently the log function isnt must.

Comment: Well, you could always wrap it in a method and document what it does.  (Ps. I tweaked the answer a bit more: I don't know if C#'s Math.Log10() likes 0 as an argument or not, but by moving the Max() inside it that issue never arises.)

Comment: Does your answer cost less/more then @Muad'Dib answer?

Comment: @nir: That's hard to say without running a benchmark.  I'd hope mine would be faster, at least for large numbers, but it may ultimately come down to arbitrary differences in implementation overhead.  Both should be fast enough for almost any practical purposes, anyway.

Comment: @nir (cont'd): I'm not really a C# programmer, but I went and ran a quick benchmark of the equivalent solutions in Perl just because I could: in that language, the character-counting solution is faster for numbers below 2^32, but slows down a lot above that point (while the log solution keeps running at about the same speed).  As I noted, this is probably due to implementation details, so other languages and platforms are likely to be different.

Comment: Hi, @DavideCannizzo. Just out of curiosity, is there a particular reason why your added en spaces around (some of) the math expressions above? I'm not convinced they really help readability (especially for single variables or in expressions like "the *p*-th power"), but I figured I'd ask before just outright reverting your edit, just in case there's something I'm missing here.

Comment: Expressions have got some internal space (such as those between the operators), so I believe they are more tidied with a quite larger space at the beginning and the end of them.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like below to account for your `0` digits returning zero length

```
private static int CountAbsoluteDigits(double p) {
    int absolute = (int)Math.Abs(p);
    if (0 == absolute)
        return 0;
    else
        return absolute.ToString().Length;
}
```

...

```
var length = CountAbsoluteDigits(12.324654);
```

This is the output I got with the numbers you supplied..

> 12.324654 -> 2
>   12 -> 2
>   0.99 -> 0
>   1.01 -> 1
>   901 -> 3
>   -0.99 -> 0
>   -9.999 -> 1

Answer (score 1):

Stealing Quintin's format:

```
private static int CountAbsoluteDigits(double p) {
    int ip = (int)p;
    int answer = 0;
    while (ip!=0) {
        answer++;
        ip/=10;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

No trick (e.g., `abs()`, `if`) required in this.

Answer (score 1):

Courtsey Muad'Dib

```
int GetLength(double value){
    return ((int)Math.Abs(value*10d)).ToString().Length - 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting to integer and converting the result to a string will only work if the value is within the range of an int. If you need values above 2 billion, you'll either need to work with logs, or deal convert the double to a string.

```
static int GetLength(double d)
{
    d = Math.Abs(d);
    if (d < 1.0) return 0;
    if (double.IsInfinity(d)) return int.MaxValue;
    if (double.IsNaN(d)) return 0;
    return (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(d)) + 1;
}

static int GetLength2(double d)
{
    d = Math.Abs(d);
    if (d < 1.0) return 0;
    if (double.IsInfinity(d)) return int.MaxValue;
    if (double.IsNaN(d)) return 0;
    string s = d.ToString("E"); // returns a string in the format "1.012435E+001"
    return int.Parse(s.Substring(s.Length - 3)) + 1;
}

static void Test(double d) { Debug.WriteLine(d + " -> " + GetLength(d) + ", " + GetLength2(d)); }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test(0);
    Test(0.125);
    Test(0.25);
    Test(0.5);
    Test(1);
    Test(2);
    Test(10);
    Test(10.5);
    Test(10.25);
    Test(10.1243542354235623542345234523452354);
    Test(999999);
    Test(1000000);
    Test(1000001);
    Test(999999.111);
    Test(1000000.111);
    Test(1000001.111);
    Test(double.MaxValue);
    Test(double.MinValue);
    Test(double.PositiveInfinity);
    Test(double.NegativeInfinity);
    Test(double.NaN);
    Test(double.Epsilon);
}
```

Results:

```
0 -> 0, 0
0.125 -> 0, 0
0.25 -> 0, 0
0.5 -> 0, 0
1 -> 1, 1
2 -> 1, 1
10 -> 2, 2
10.5 -> 2, 2
10.25 -> 2, 2
10.1243542354236 -> 2, 2
999999 -> 6, 6
1000000 -> 7, 7
1000001 -> 7, 7
999999.111 -> 6, 6
1000000.111 -> 7, 7
1000001.111 -> 7, 7
1.79769313486232E+308 -> 309, 309
-1.79769313486232E+308 -> 309, 309
Infinity -> 2147483647, 2147483647
-Infinity -> 2147483647, 2147483647
NaN -> 0, 0
4.94065645841247E-324 -> 0, 0
```