# C# replace in long variable

Tags: c#, long-integer

I have a large number like:

```
1012223457
```

I need to set the 3rd-most-significant digit in this number to `3`. How can I achieve that? Is there any way to do it without converting to string and without adding "20000000" to it?

Comment: No, you covered it. Why is adding `20000000` bad?

Comment: There's not much point in asking "I need to do X without using Y or Z" without explaining why you can't use Y or Z.

Comment: cause it can be 9 numbers long, not always 10

Comment: i answered about why not adding 200000, i need replace the number to "3" it can be 10000000 or 10900000 i also need to replace the 3rd number with "3"

Comment: What other interesting requirements you've omitted? Like "use only XXXXX operations" or something similar? Can it be 50 digits long? (or you mean "long" as C# `long` also known as `System.Int64`)?

Comment: hm... it can be 11-12 digits long max

Comment: Why can't you convert it to string?

Comment: How about use division to get the top 1 or 2 digits, modulo to get the bottom 7 digits, and stick the 3 in between, using only arithmetic operations?

Comment: int i = 1012223457;
         int j = i / 100000000 * 100000000 + 3 * 10000000 + i % 10000000;

Comment: @RenniePet  Problem is that you need to account for potentially shorter `number` like `101223`

Comment: What is the business value out doing it?

Comment: ah goddamn i can convert it to string, just doesn't want to, cause i got to conver it back to long again. that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best way to do what you asked for OP, you have to use ToString for the best and most reliable solution, but nevertheless, here's a sample that does what you asked for:

```
var a = 10000000L;
var pows = Enumerable.Range(0, 16).Select(x => (long)Math.Pow(10, x));
var d = pows.First(x => a / x == 0);
var thirdDigit = (a / (d / 1000)) % 100;
a += (long)((3 - thirdDigit) * (d / 1000));
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do it without a string. Most of the convolution is determining the length of the number without using string. So rather I use a mathematical trick:

```
long number = 1012223457;
number += (long)(2*Math.Pow(10.0,(double)((int)(Math.Log10(Math.Max(Math.Abs(number), 0.5)) + 1)-3)));
```

The `2*` is the value you wanted to add.

The solution is fugly, but it should work.

I didn't even think that the trick for the length of a number would be in StackOverflow but you can find information on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864991/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-number-in-net) . Coincidentally the code provided was in C#.

So one has to go with a pretty complex method without using strings, but would require math functions to compensate. I'd probably go with something that uses `string` because readability would be much improved.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:

[How can I get a count of the total number of digits in a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483886/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-the-total-number-of-digits-in-a-number)

Thus it is posssible to do like this:

```
int digitpos = 5;
long number = 1080511231123;
int numbertoset = 3;

int digitcount = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(number) + 1);
long exp = (long)Math.Pow(10, digitcount - digitpos);
if (exp == 0) throw new ArgumentException("The number does not contain required digit.");
int targetdigit = (int)(number / exp) % 10;
int multiplier = numbertoset - targetdigit;
long result = number + multiplier * exp;
```

To replace the target digit I had to calculate its value first.

Answer (score -1):

The small usage of ToString results in a much cleaner code. Keep in mind that I am still using mathematical functions to do the change, no string manipulation involved.

```
   var number = 123456789;
   var length = number.ToString().Length;
   var multiplier = Math.Pow(10, length - 3):
   var oldDigit = Math.Floor(number / multiplier) % 10;
   var change = 3 - oldDigit;
   number += change * multiplier;
```

Comment: Without even seeing whether your code works or not, the question specifically says "Is there any way to do it without converting to string".

Comment: True, but I had the impression that OP meant "do not work with strings to replace the digit". I'll wait for an answer from OP first. And @VDohnal oh man, I must be tired.

Comment: You still convert `number` to a `string` via `ToString()` to get the length.

Comment: Funny this is the accepted answer yet it converts to a string which the OP told us we couldn't use. Chuckle